# OpenGL - Should I store Attribute/Uniform locations?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Are `glGetUniformLocation` and `glGetAttribLocation` time consuming?

Which way is better?

1. Call `glGetAttribLocation` or `glGetUniformLocation` every time I need it ?
2. Store locations in varables and use them when needed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether on Android or iPhone, for an opengl surface you will have methods like:
**onSurfaceCreated and onSurfaceChanged**,
get into the habit of fetching uniforms and attributes here in these 2 methods.

The only way you can make rendering faster (which will soon become your priority when your code crosses 1000 lines of code) is by only having **gluseprogram, glbindbuffer, texture binds** and other binds inside onDrawFrame method, **always cache variables inside onSurfaceCreated and onSurfaceChanged**

Comment: Good answer. Attributes, uniforms, and other variables used inside shaders should be cached inside init() methods, and not the draw_Frame() methods.

Answer (score 10):

> Which way is better?

Think about it. No matter how fast `glGetUniformLocation` and `glGetAttribLocation` are, they *cannot* be faster than just fetching a variable. So if you are concerned about performance, then use the method that is always faster.

Answer (score 8):

According to my tests, fetching such locations took about 100~200 times the amount of time that it takes for a single `glDrawElements` call. This is only an estimate based on `System.nanoTime()`, but I think it's save to say that it's worth storing them in variables on initialization.

Comment: This is a much better answer. (I hope the data is correct of course, but I could imagine it is, because getting attributes is synchronous and drawing is not).